# SignalR - Passing back a Client's response to the server

Tags: signalr

I am calling a client-side method from the server that is essentially a Javascript confirm dialog. If the client clicks the`Cancel` button on the dialog I want to delete their token from local storage (essentially logging them out) ...

```
sessionStorage.removeItem('access-token');
```

If the client clicks the `OK` button I want to do the same on a different client (I have the connectionId of this client stored on the server side). So I need a way for the server to know which option the client chose (`OK` or `Cancel`).

How would I go about taking the client's choice and passing it back to the server, so the server could call the "Logout" Javascript on the proper client?

Comment: Was my answer something you were looking for, or were you looking for a different implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a couple of options.

You could send a message back to the `Hub` once the user has clicked on a button.

**Hub**

```
[HubName("message")]
public class MessageHub : Hub
{
    public void sendmessage(bool logout)
    {
        Clients.Caller(????).logoutuser(logout); //However you identify who to logout??
    }
}
```

**Client**

```
var hub = $.connection.message;

hub.client.logoutuser = function(message) {
    if (message.logout = true) {
        sessionStorage.removeItem('access-token');
    }
}

hub.server.sendmessage(true); //result of the user's click OK -> True, Cancel -> False

$.connection.hub.start().done(function () { });
```

Or you could hit an API that gets the connection for *some?* user who you're wanting to log out.

**API**

```
[RoutePrefix("api/messaging")]
public class MessagingController : ApiController
{
    [Route("")]
    public void Post(Message message)
    {
        var notificationHub = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MessageHub>();
        if (notificationHub != null)
        {
            try
            { 
                notificationHub.Clients.User(message.UserName).logoutuser(message);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Client**

```
function notifyController(responseObj) {

$.ajax({
        url: '/api/Messaging/',
        type: 'POST',
        data: responseObj, // some object containing the users response information?
        success: function (data) { return; },
        error: function (ex) { return; }
    });
}
```